# perform redirection if event time plus 4 hours is more than current time in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

There is a variable which contains event time. I want to redirect user if event time + 04:38 is more than current time.

Below is the code i have tried:

```
var deadline = getDayInstance("Monday","08:00:59")
function getDayInstance(day,time) {

    const days = {"Sunday":0,"Monday":1,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":4,"Friday":5,"Saturday":6};
    if(days[day]!==undefined)
        var dayINeed = days[day];
    else
        var dayINeed = 2; // for Tuesday
    const today = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").isoWeekday();
    var dt;
    // if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
    if (today <= dayINeed) {
        dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").isoWeekday(dayINeed).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
    }
    else {
        dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
    }
    console.log("Event Time: "+dt);
    var maxLimit = Date.parse(moment(time,'HH:mm:ss').tz("America/Los_Angeles").add({"hours":4,"minutes":43,"seconds":33}).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
    var now = Date.parse(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
    if(maxLimit < now)
    {
        dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
        window.setVideo = false;
    }
    console.log(moment(time,'HH:mm:ss').tz("America/Los_Angeles").add({"hours":4,"minutes":43,"seconds":33}).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
    console.log(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
    return dt;
}

var maxLimit = Date.parse(moment(deadline,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').add({"hours":4,"minutes":43,"seconds":33}).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
var now = Date.parse(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
if(maxLimit>=now){
    var redirectTo = $("#lp-pom-button-673").attr('href');
    if(redirectTo.length > 3){
        window.location.href = redirectTo;
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = "https://******/";
    }
}
```

I need to maintain timezone in calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of this after refining the process theoretically and then try to implement it in JS. Below is the new code that can be used for this.

```
var deadline = getDayInstance("Tuesday", "02:32:00");
var maxLimit,now;
function getDayInstance(day,time) {
    const days = {"Sunday":0,"Monday":1,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":4,
                    "Friday":5,"Saturday":6};
    if(days[day]!==undefined)
        var dayINeed = days[day];
    else
        var dayINeed = 2; // for Tuesday
    const today = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").isoWeekday();
    var dt;
    // if we haven't yet passed the day of the week that I need:
    if (today <= dayINeed) {
      dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").isoWeekday(dayINeed)
        .format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
    }
    else {
      dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").add(1, 'weeks')
        .isoWeekday(dayINeed).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
    }
    var d = new Date(dt);
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 4);
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 43);
    d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 32);
    max = Date.parse(d);
    now = Date.parse(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
    if(maxLimit < now)
    {
        dt = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").add(1, 'weeks')
            .isoWeekday(dayINeed).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"T"+time;
    }
    return dt;
}
if(maxLimit>=now){
    var redirectTo = $("#lp-pom-button-673").attr('href');
    if(redirectTo.length > 3){
        window.location.href = redirectTo;
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = "https://******/";
    }
}
```